# What are the ascii numbers for shift and control?

Tags: c

I is trying to makey makey a program that will detect when certain keys are pushed. My only problem is that I dont know the nombers that corrospond to the shift key and control keys. I am writing this code for a game. Here are teh codes:

```
switch(event->keyval) {
    case ?:
        printf("Shift key was pressed");
    break;
    case ??:
        printf("Control key waas pressed");
    break;
}
```

What can replace ""?"" and ""??""

Also, if possible, my answer SHOULD be able to fit in a `char` type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get state of the shift and control buttons in GTK, you need to apply bitwise AND to the event state.

```
if(event->state & GDK_SHIFT_MASK)
{
    printf("Shift key was pressed");
}
else if(event->state & GDK_CONTROL_MASK)
{
    printf("Control key was pressed");
}
```

Alternatively, you can use macros (or their values, but please **don't**) defined in [gdkkeysyms.h](https://code.woboq.org/gtk/gtk/gdk/gdkkeysyms.h.html)

> #define GDK_KEY_Shift_L 0xffe1
>
> #define GDK_KEY_Shift_R 0xffe2
>
> #define GDK_KEY_Control_L 0xffe3
>
> #define GDK_KEY_Control_R 0xffe4

```
switch(event->keyval) {
    case GDK_KEY_Shift_L:
        printf("Left shift key was pressed");
    break;
    case GDK_KEY_Shift_R:
        printf("Right shift key was pressed");
    break;
    case GDK_KEY_Control_L:
        printf("Left control key was pressed");
    break;
    case GDK_KEY_Control_R:
        printf("Right control key was pressed");
    break;
}
```